# Openmdao: How can I deactivate a constraint?

Tags: openmdao

Let's say I want to run multiple optimization setups, where the difference between them is which constraints apply. Is there a way to deactivate a constraint that has been added to the driver, or do I need to redefine the driver for every case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As of OpenMDAO V2.2, there is no API methods to remove constraints. The simplest thing to do is simply to re-instantiate the problem/group.